# Is there a data Stack Exchange query for close vote versus down votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes, data-explorer

Can I get a query for individual users or as a group where they succeed in closing a question and they get a down vote that day, versus any regular day?  Is it possible to know the frequency of closed questions *askers* who may down vote on that event versus a normal active day?  Down vote a question closer versus any regular day?

Similar questions on *revenge downvoting* say don't both to leave a comment, etc.  However, when you succeed in closing a question, all of the people are explicitly listed.  My question is to help quantify whether this encourages revenge voting against close voters.

Comment: I have close voted a couple of questions but I hardly ever get downvotes...

Comment: @rene Yes, I am not really complaining about the amount of answer down-votes; I have voted on over 1000 close votes with maybe 20-40 downvotes total (and I think you have ~150 close votes?).  Anyways, **if** it is retaliation, then the down-vote of the answer is not deserved.  It seems pretty apparent if the 'closee' down-voted all 5 listed closer; doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query isn't possible with the public [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) data. The [Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/186281) table only contains the `UserId` if the cast vote is for starting a bounty or setting a question as a favorite. All other actions are anonymous.

This type of query would require the assistance of either a community manager or a Stack Exchange developer. Moderators aren't privy to individual user votes either.

Comment: Is it worth asking on stack exchange meta?  Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570345/what-is-the-most-commonly-used-free-arm-development-toolchain) where all five close voters received a negative answer votes within minutes of each other.  I don't care about the 'reputation', but I don't like technically correct answers down-voted.  I probably have worse answers that deserve a down-vote.